# Check50 doesn't seem to compile while clang and make show no errors

Tags: compiler-errors, cs50

I am part of edx;s cs50 online course.Right now I'm in week 3 and trying to solve plurality([This is the link to the page](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/plurality/)).The code seems to work perfectly and compiles with both clang and make(One of cs50's helping tools).But when I try to check my code with check50 cs50/problems/2020/x/plurality it says it cannot compile.Here is the code I have written.
I have written it in c.

```js
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name,int candlen);
void print_winner(int candlen);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");


        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name,candidate_count))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");

        }

    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner(candidate_count);
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name,int candlen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candlen; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name,name)==0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(int candlen)
{

    int Present_best = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    if (candidates[i].votes != 0)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes>candidates[Present_best].votes)
        {
            Present_best = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0;i<candlen;i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == candidates[Present_best].votes)
        printf("%s\n",candidates[i].name);
        }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec:

> You should not modify anything else in plurality.c other than the implementations of the vote and print_winner functions (and the inclusion of additional header files, if you’d like).

These are the provided/required function signatures:

```
// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);
```

The requirement may seem strict or harsh. While the only thing at stake here is a grade, if one doesn't follow the spec provided by a boss or client, it could translate to real money.